# CkEditor : how to get actual text size without HTML tags

Tags: html, ckeditor, content-length

How to get text size in CkEditor without all HTML tags? I want to restrict user not to exceed certain text length and want to display correct message with actual length of entered text. `CKEDITOR.instances.TextAreId.getData().length` returns the length of text with HTML tags.

I know I can achieve this using regular expressions but if there is already something then I would prefer that.

Thanks.

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15067729/1960455) to [How to extract plain text from ckeditor generated html in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065132) tells you how to get the Text without tags.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the text length inside the CKEditor instance, is to use this code:

```
var length = CKEDITOR.instances.myCKEditor.document.getBody().getText().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are is a [Word Count](http://ckeditor.com/addon/wordcount) plugin for CKEditor that may help you as well. It displays the number of characters and words.